# Nitrogen how to add element id

Tags: html, erlang, nitrogen

I can't figure out how to get Nitrogen to generate an actual `id` attribute of an html element.  For example, In index.erl:

`#panel { id = "test" }` or `#panel { id = test }`

the generated html element looks like this:

`<div class="wfid_test"></div>`.

but what I want is:

`<div id="test"></div>`

so I can use an anchor link like `<a href="#test">Scroll Down to Test</a>` to reference the id.

This is basic HTML that has been around forever, so I'm sure Nitrogen must have some way of doing it, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 'html_id' element instead of 'id':

```
 #panel{ html_id=test, body="Test target" }
```

it will render as:

```
<div id="test" class="wfid_temp990008">Test target</div>
```

you can include both 'id' and 'html_id' elements if you need the class for CSS as well:

```
#panel{ id=test, html_id=test, body="Test target" }
```

renders as:

```
<div id="test" class="wfid_temp990008 wfid_test">Test target</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#panel { id = test }` should work fine.  Just use atom instead of sting.

Comment: Still doesn't create the `id` attribute.  The atom has the same effect as the quoted string: `<div class="wfid_test></div>`.